# Android dynamic tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost

How create dynamic tab in android?. If user want to add  tab dynamically on the `tabhost`. How it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this blog.

in this example add tab by click on button

check out http://sankarganesh-info-exchange.blogspot.com/2011/04/adding-tabs-dynamically-in-android.html

another link add tab from option menu

http://knol.google.com/k/tabs-and-tabhost#

Comment: once see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097931/android-add-new-tab-when-button-click-like-google-chrome-new-button

Answer (score 2):

The procedure to add a tab (whether dynamically or otherwise) is similar. You need

1. A `TabHost` object
2. A `TabSpec` (that you could create dynamically)
3. `tabHost.addTab()` method

You need to set up the target activity for this tab in the same way that you do for creating "static" tabs (via `tabSpec.setContent()`).

Have you tried the [Android Tab Layout tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)? What is it that is preventing you from adding the tab dynamically?

By the way, if you do not have a view in the first place, then look at [TabContentFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabContentFactory.html).