# Android — Add new tab when button click like Google Chrome new button?

Tags: android, button, browser

In general, everything is working on Google Chrome.  When the new tab button is clicked, a new tab is generated. In the same way, I want to add a new tab in the Android browser. How to do this — does anyone have any idea?

1. First, is it possible in Android?
2. If possible, how to do this?

   [image]

When I click on the `+` button, a new tab should be generated. How to do this?

Comment: What sorts of tabs are you using? `PagerTabStrip`? Tabs in the action bar? `TabHost` and `TabWidget`? ViewPagerIndicator's tabs? Something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare i want google chrome tabs like we click button new tab is open....

Comment: That's nice. Please click the "edit" link below your question, and modify the question to show us the code where you are defining your tabs. If you do not have such code, then please answer the question that I posed in my first comment. If you do not understand that question, you need to decide how you are going to display your tabs before we can tell you how to add tabs dynamically.

Comment: you can tell me process how to do that one i have no idea

Comment: I think CommmonsWare means the actual method for adding Tab is based on what kind of tabs you are using, tabs in action bar or TabHost.

Comment: Android add tab is possible but different new tab different Url not role propely...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok Here is the code but it's an example only you may need to modify the code as per your requirement. I am giving you all the files code here hope you getting answer.

Your Manifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.dynamictab"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BlankActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is your activity_main.xml file for Tab activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none" 
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
            <Button android:id="@+id/add_tab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:text="Add"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Put your TabWidget into the HorizontalScrollView so when more tabs are add it can scrolling and the Add but is out side of HorizontalScrollView. Every time you click on tab it will add new tab in TabWidget.

Here the code for tab_event.xml This layout will inflate and add into tab. You can change the style and its contain a single Button so you can add drawable image with text also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_event"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:text="Default Tab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is your MainActivity.java file

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    private static int tabIndex = 0;
    private TabHost tabHost;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabHost = getTabHost();

        addTab();

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.add_tab)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tabIndex++;
                addTab();
            }
        });
    }
    private void addTab(){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflate = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);

        Button tabBtn = (Button)layoutInflate.inflate(R.layout.tab_event, null);
        tabBtn.setText("Tab "+tabIndex);
        Intent tabIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BlankActivity.class);

        setupTab(tabBtn, tabIntent,"Tab "+tabIndex);
    }
    protected void setupTab(View tabBtn, Intent setClass,String tag) {
        TabSpec setContent = tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabBtn).setContent(setClass);
        tabHost.addTab(setContent);
    }
}
```

And here is the BlankActivity.java file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BlankActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(BlankActivity.this);
        tv.setText("Blank activity");
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

Comment: In BlankActivity each time create for specific tab so in that TextView also be create new one thats way you can add WebView instead of TextView in it. Or you can just create your layout with containing addressbar, webview and searchbar and set in the blank activity

Comment: yes for individual tab container it create new instance of the Activity and you can use single xml same as. They are differently treat in memory also so no worry about it.

Comment: you can set minWidth and maxWidth in button layout as I have set as wrap_content so when more tab are created the button size was set based on text, either you set in layout_width or min or max width

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18909/discussion-between-nagarjunareddy-and-pratik)

Comment: TabActivity is deprecated. Better not to use it.

Comment: As `TabActivity` is deprecated, what are the alternatives to achieve it??

Answer (score 2):

For button click create a new tabspec.

```
TabSpeec spec = th.newTabSpec("tag");
spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory(){
    //What ever thing you want to display inside the tab
    TextView text = new TextView(CONTEXT);
    text.setText("New tab");
    return(text);
    }
});
spec.setIndicator("New");
th.addTab(spec);
```

Use the following youtube tutorial as reference. Its simple.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcKSFlYEqYY

Answer (score 1):

Create an Activity as below:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            WebView wv=new WebView(this);
        setContentView(wv);
    }
}
```

Now use @Partik's method to add a new tab, on each + button click:

```
private void addTab(){
    Button tabBtn = new Button(MainActivity.this);
    tabBtn.setText("Tab "+tabIndex);
    Intent tabIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);

    setupTab(tabBtn, tabIntent,"Tab "+tabIndex);
}
```