# Android Browser: Hiding URL bar and progress bar

Tags: java, android, webview, webkit, actionbarsherlock

I am developing an Android web browser, I would like to implement a Custom URL bar into my app for my users to navigate to their own webpages rather than trying to Google everything. Anyone know how to do this?

I'm not sure if it matters, but I have `ActionbarSherlock` added as a Library on my project.

Anyone's help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following youtube tutorial as reference. Its simple.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcKSFlYEqYY

and see this question..

[Android — Add new tab when button click like Google Chrome new button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097931/android-add-new-tab-when-button-click-like-google-chrome-new-button)