# Android: How does one go about having the user click a button to create (not go to) a new activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse

What I'm trying to do is make an Android app that makes use of tabs, and when a user clicks a certain button I want a new tab to appear. I was wondering if this is possible, and if anyone could provide details or direction on this.

Basically:
One main activity where you can create new tabs.
This main activity has tabs, which the new one would be apart of.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of solutions [Android — Add new tab when button click like Google Chrome new button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097931/android-add-new-tab-when-button-click-like-google-chrome-new-button).

I hope that will be enough for good start.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, a shame I couldn't find it via search. Thanks again